# Skip to the string and take other items

Tags: c#, linq

I have the list of folder segments `"c:\","user","temp","subfolder1","subfolder2"`
I would like to find all items after `"temp"` item and join them. I have solved it using two methods: First I find an index of "temp" and then use another Linq method.

Maybe there is a Skip method that accepts not only the index but also the name?
Something like this

```
directories.Skip("Temp").Skip(1).Take(1000)
```

My current code

```
var findIndex = directories.FindIndex(f=>f.ToLower()=="temp");
if (findIndex != -1)
{
    filePath = string.Join(@"\", directories.Skip(findIndex).Skip(1).Take(1000));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`SkipWhile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.skipwhile?view=net-6.0):

```
directories.SkipWhile(x => x != "Temp").Skip(1).Take(1000)
```